# NLog FileTarget Configuration, one file every hour or 50mb which contains creation timestamp in filename

Tags: nlog

I need to replicate the functionality of an existing (very old) logging system with NLog.
The current logging system creates log files that are named like this:

"some root folder" + ${date:format=yyMMdd}${date:format=HHmmss}" + "Something.log"

eg: ...\230525\123021Something.log

The log file timestamp in the name is the creation timestamp, and a log file must not
contain more than 50mb.

What i now tried is the following in the file target configuration:

- FileName = rootfolder +
  @"${cached:cached=true:Inner=${date:format=yyMMdd}${date:format=HHmmss}" + postFix + @":CacheKey=${date:format=HH}"
- ArchiveAboveSize = BytesInMB * 20,
- ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Hour,
- ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Sequence,

This now is creating a file with the correct file size, but the cache does not get
reset when an archived file is created. I tried to add the ${sequenceid} to the cache key
but that resulted in a log file per second.

How can i reset the cache when the file is archived or achieve a similiar effect?

One log file every hour or 50mb, where every file contains the timestamp when it was created?

Thanks!
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you implement the rolling like this:

```
FileName= rootfolder + @"${date:format=yyMMdd-HH}" + postFix,
ArchiveAboveSize = BytesInMB * 20,
```

And remove other settings (Ex. `ArchiveEvery` + `ArchiveNumbering`). Since the `${date}` will automatically ensure hourly-rolling.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic